# CMS: Extra content at the end of the document at feed

Tags: php, feed

I've recently have some issues with the feed of my `CMS` and I'm scratching the problem every time but I didn't solve it by good.

I have a `VPS` with this `CMS` and when I make `PHP` queries with a connection `PHP`script to fill some tables, the XML of the feed gets crazy and stops working properly, the thing is if the latest new is this post with the `PHP` queries integrated in the template, the `RSS` feed starts to malfunction. If it's the second or the next ones, the `RSS` works without any problem.

Could anyone help me to solve the problem with this `PHP`issue? I think it's because the query is overlapping on the `RSS`or something like that. Thanks you very much

The URL of the feed is : http://heroeswar.es/feed/

The problem that you can see in it is the next one:

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 380 at column 71:

Extra content at the end of the document

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Nginx Error Log for queries:

2015/05/11 17:28:08 [error] 4101#0: *6758 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare DBConect() (previously declared in .../DBFunctions.php:7) in .../DBFunctions.php on line 14" while reading response header from upstream, client: 84.123.182.185, server: heroeswar.es, request: "GET /feed/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "heroeswar.es"
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$DBservername = "***";
$DBusername = "***";
$DBpassword = "***";

function DBConect(){
    $DBservername = "***";
    $DBusername = "***";
    $DBpassword = "***";    
    $DBcon = mysql_connect($DBservername,$DBusername,$DBpassword);
    mysql_select_db('HOTS_Heroes',$DBcon) or die('No se pudo seleccionar la                               base de datos');
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$DBcon);   
    return $DBcon;
}

function drawRotacion($heroesNameArray){
    $BDcon = DBConect();
    echo('<table class="guidestable" align="center">');
    echo('<tbody>');
    echo('<tr>');
    foreach($heroesNameArray as $heroeName){
        $heroeInfoArray = getHeroeInfoByName($heroeName);

    echo'<td><a title='.$heroeInfoArray[heroeName].'href="'.$heroeInfoArray[pageLink].'"><img src="'.$heroeInfoArray[infoboxImageLink].'" width="110" height="110" /></a>   </td>';

}
    echo('</tr>
    <tr>
    ');
foreach($heroesNameArray as $heroeName2){
    $heroeInfoArray2 = getHeroeInfoByName($heroeName2);
    echo'<td style="text-align: center"><a  href="'.$heroeInfoArray2[guideLink].'">Guia '.$heroeInfoArray2[heroeName].'</a></td>';
    }
    echo('
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>');
    }
?>
```

Comment: To help you your question has to be as complete as possible, providing the smallest possible source to reproduce the problem

Comment: As seen in the last row, you are trying to declare function DBConect() twice. You probably include some library more than once.

Comment: I've been seeing the code and it only declare the function once, I put the code in here to check it out, the plugin to allow `PHP`code must use the include twice when it refers to the `feed`because it's only declared once.